# c++17 language extension and std:c++17 flag

Tags: visual-studio, c++17, compiler-flags, structured-bindings, if-constexpr

I'm confused by different errors I have in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.11):

```
'if constexpr' is a C++17 language extension
```

and

```
language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'
```

I know that adding /std:c++17 flag will solve these issues but why are there two different messages? What is a difference between language extension and a compiler flag requirement?

I am more interested about this thing, because I'm writing a game in Unreal Engine 4.24 I can use 'if constexpr', but I can't use 'structured bindings' even though I'm using the same compiler.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if constexpr` is an exceedingly useful langauge construct from C++17. It's very handy for implementing, for example, many optimizations within the standard library.

As such, when Visual Studio 15.3 initially implemented `if constexpr`, it was used liberally in their standard library implementation even when compiled in C++14 mode. But since much of that code is in headers which, as far as the compiler is concerned, is part of your source code, that means *you* get to use it too. To allow for that, they made [using `if constexpr` from C++14 a warning](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/) rather than an error, a warning they disabled within their headers with `#pragma`s.

However, despite MSVC's documentation *calling* it a warning, it is issued by the compiler as [a error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-c4984?view=vs-2019), which can be suppressed.

The difference in wording between these two conditions is therefore likely to be born of the fact that the `if constexpr` "error" is considered to be a "warning", despite presenting itself as an "error" by default.

Comment: However, the OP explicitly says they are getting *errors*, not *warnings*, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I'm merely repeating what MSVC's own [release notes say](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/): "*“if constexpr” is supported in /std:c++14 with a warning that can be suppressed, delighting template metaprogramming library authors everywhere.*"

Comment: @JörgWMittag And anyway, from a standard perspective they are all just "diagnostics", without differentiating their seriousness.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I found further information; they explicitly call it a warning in their documentation, but it *presents* as an error by default. I guess the fact that it can be suppressed is how Microsoft considers them different.

Comment: Oh dear MSVC and their own standards, so they put 'if constexpr' inside c++14! That's explaining a lot. Thank You!